# Why does some files not show up in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I started Eclipse and opened a project that is in a Git repo. However, a folder with some files does not show. Why is that?

The files are committed, and I am on the right branch so it is not that.

```
$ git status
On branch feat57
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The files exists:

```
$ ls -d html/catalogue/*/
html/catalogue/article/  html/catalogue/backup/  html/catalogue/projects/  html/catalogue/reports/
$ ls html/catalogue/projects/
projects_edit.php  projects_list.php  projects_new.php  projects.php  projects_view.php
```

Apache finds the files when I access it through a browser.

Two icons seems to show that something is wrong. However, I don't know what they mean.

[image: Project explorer]

As you can see, there's something fishy with folders `html` and `catalogue`. The folder that is not showing is in `catalogue`. You can also see that `projects` does not show.

Comment: If you make any changes on the command line outside of Eclipse, you need to refresh (F5) or enable _Refresh using native hooks or polling_. If refreshing does not help, check in the _Navigator_ view if the files are filtered out by other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are locking at your project from the "Package Explorer" view. This is a special view that doesn't represent the file system. It focuses on source and ressource folders, which you can identify by the little brownish symbol inside the "folder" icon. I suspect your `catalogue` folder is excluded from the build path somehow.

If it's not, try refreshing the project (mark the project and hit F5).

Finally, if you want a view showing the file system, go to Window->Show View->Navigator.

Comment: Pressing F5 resolved it. It feels strange though, since restarting Eclipse did not help.

Comment: @klutt restarting Eclipse doesn't seem to refresh your projects. I've had that issue several times.

Comment: @klutt In _Window > Preferences: General > Workspace_ check the checkbox _Refresh using native hooks or polling_ or press F5 everytime you change files outside of Eclipse (for Git you do not need to use the command line).